# Get the value of my dropdown list with AJAX

Tags: ajax, jsf

Here is the code in my View, I have a dropdown list and basically what i want is that when i click on any item on this list I get the value of the item and it complete the input in the name field.

I managed to do this on JS with a button that load the input but the pb is that it's in Ajax and to be honest I am knew to this and I don't really understand how to make it functional. Should I do it using basic JS ?

```
<h:outputText value="Name" styleClass="section-label"/>
    <h:inputText id="name" value="#{contextSchemeDetailBean.contextScheme.schemeName}"
                 required="true" maxlength="255"
                 requiredMessage="Please fill out 'Name' field."
                 label="Name" styleClass="section-content input-section">
    <f:validateLength maximum="255"/>
    </h:inputText>
<h:outputText value="Code List" styleClass="section-label"/>
<p:autoComplete id="inputCodeList" required="true"
                requiredMessage="Please fill out 'Code List' field."
                styleClass="section-content input-section"
                completeMethod="#{codeListBean.completeInput}"
                dropdown="true" scrollHeight="220">
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{codeListBaseBean.codeList.guid}"/>
</p:autoComplete>
```

I dont know if I am really clear, if not dont hesitate to ask. Thanks !!

Comment: You tagged your question waaaay to broad. Yes you might be using java and javascript but the 'issue' is not in your javascript code, or in your java code. Hence you get answers that are not really applicable to your case. One question, what do you mean by _" and it complete the input in the name field."_, do you mean it should be appended to what already is in the `inputText`

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, not really like an append but more like a clear and a new input.
Basically you pick an item in the dropdown list and there is a SQL request that pick the corresponding element (name for example) for this item and complete the input related to this !

Comment: Well, in the listener in the `<p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{codeListBaseBean.codeList.guid}"/>` you can do that SQL thing and than 'update' the inputText as is basic 'ajax'. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Comment: If questions are answered accept the answer and leave the question as is please

Answer (score -1):

here is a code you can start with if needed any help just ask :)

```html
 <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#yourid').on('change', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        var mytextbox = e.target.value;
        $.get('/' + mytextbox,function(data) {
          console.log(data);
          $('#yourid').append('<option value="0" disable="true" selected="true">=== Select something ===</option>');
}


    </script>
```

```js
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        $that = $(this);
        $('textarea').val(function(){
            return $(this).prop('defaultValue') + ' '+$that.val();
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<select>
    <option value="">select one</option>
    <option value="aaaa">aaaa</option>
    <option value="bbbb">bbbb</option>
    <option value="cccc">cccc</option>
    <option value="dddd">dddd</option>
    <option value="eeee">eeee</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>
```

You Can run it from "Run code snippet" button

Comment: I'll go this way, thanks ! I will tell you what I get using this ! Thanks again for your consideration !

Comment: just a little update @Sox-  easy use this jquery code   this does what you need
<select>
    <option value="">select one</option>
    <option value="aaaa">aaaa</option>
    <option value="bbbb">bbbb</option>
    <option value="cccc">cccc</option>
    <option value="dddd">dddd</option>
    <option value="eeee">eeee</option>
</select>
<textarea></textarea>

$(function(){
    $('select').change(function(){
        $that = $(this);
        $('textarea').val(function(){
            return $(this).prop('defaultValue') + ' '+$that.val();
        });
    });
});

Comment: You ran into not to good tagging by OP. It is not javascript related at all but a JSF issue/question.

Answer (score -1):

It Seems, you are using struts? If so you can use selector tag.

In Struts 2 , you can use the  tag to create a HTML drop down box.

```
<s:select label="What's your favor search engine" 
    headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Search Engines"
    list="searchEngine" 
    name="yourSearchEngine" />
```

find full example from here: https://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-sselect-drop-down-box-example/

Comment: I will try Justin's code first if It s not working I ll try yours, thx anyway for your response !! ;)

Comment: No, @Sox is not using struts but JSF. **As can be seen from the tags**